# Why android studio need to sync every change in gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I know my question is something like axioms, but why android-studio require sync for every change in the gradle even this change adding a space or comment.

As far as I know running the application will make that, Can someone explain why this behavior required in gradle?

Answer (score 1):

Because gradle downloads libraries or removes according to your changes

Answer (score 0):

> why android-studio require sync for every change in the gradle even this change adding a space or comment

It is difficult for the IDE to determine, automatically, what a syntactically-relevant change is to `build.gradle`, so it errs on the side of caution.

> As far as I know running the application will make that

Yes, but you may want to see the impacts of the changes (e.g., new dependencies) before running the app.